# multirow that has more lines than the rows it spans

Tags: multirow

I am sorry if this is already has been asked, but I can't found any solution. When I have multirow, that has bigger height that all rows is spanned, this is doesn't stretch the height of row. 
In the example here the text started with 'Unproperly height' doesn't automatically set 
properly height of row.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}, breaklinks=true, pdftex=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, left=1.5cm, right=1cm, top=1.7cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}

%For tables
\newdimen{\newtblsparewidth}
\newdimen{\newtblstarfactor}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{White}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\arrayrulewidth=1pt

\setlength{\parskip}{1.7ex}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
This section defines options.

\setlength{\newtblsparewidth}{\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\tabcolsep-2\tabcolsep-2\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\newtblstarfactor}{\newtblsparewidth / \real{3}}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X|X|l|}
\multicolumn{1}{|>{\columncolor{Blue}\color{White}}m{0.33\newtblsparewidth}}{\centering \textbf{Name}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\columncolor{Blue}\color{White}}m{0.33\newtblsparewidth}}{\centering \textbf{Possible values}} & \multicolumn{1}{|>{\columncolor{Blue}\color{White}}m{0.33\newtblsparewidth}|}{\centering \textbf{Description}} \\ *\nobreakhline
\multicolumn{1}{|m{0.33\newtblsparewidth}}{Enabled} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{0.33\newtblsparewidth}}{Boolean} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{0.33\newtblsparewidth}|}{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been}
\\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|m{0.33\newtblsparewidth}}{Has user} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{0.33\newtblsparewidth}}{Integer} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{0.33\newtblsparewidth}|}{\multirow{2}{0.33\newtblsparewidth}{\textbf{Unproperly height} Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem 
Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
}} \\ \cline{1-2}
\multicolumn{1}{|m{0.33\newtblsparewidth}}{Not User} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{0.33\newtblsparewidth}|}{Integer} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{} \\ \hline

\multicolumn{1}{|m{0.33\newtblsparewidth}}{Pass} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{0.33\newtblsparewidth}}{String} & 
\multicolumn{1}{|m{0.33\newtblsparewidth}|}{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. .} \\ \hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

This text is override the next row.
Here is same in pdf http://web-engineering.com.ua/mtest4.pdf

How I can force row auto height i this case?

Comment: the similar question there http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26080/how-can-i-achieve-proper-vertical-spacing-for-long-blocks-of-text-within-a-mult
But is there any way to set all spanned rows the same height and valign center?

Comment: Sorry to reopen the discussion so lately; could you please give a "real case" example? My impression is that you're wanting to use the wrong tool for this job.