# Vertical Alignment in multirow using cells with >1 lines

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable, multirow

I want to vertically align (best would be to center) the text ("TEST") in the left (yellow) column of the following table. It works fine with multirow when every row has exactly the hight of one line:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,a4paper,12pt,pdftex]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.025\textwidth}|p{0.775\textwidth}|>{\centering arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}|}
 & \textbf{foo} & \textbf{bar} \\
\hline
\hline 
\endfirsthead
 & \textbf{foo} & \textbf{bar} \\
\hline
\hline
\endhead
\cellcolor{yellow}& short text & 1 \\
\cline{2-3} 
\cellcolor{yellow} & short text & 2 \\
\cline{2-3} 
\cellcolor{yellow} & short text & 3 \\
\cline{2-3} 
\cellcolor{yellow} & short text & 4 \\
\cline{2-3} 
\cellcolor{yellow} & short text & 5 \\
\cline{2-3} 
\cellcolor{yellow} & short text & 6 \\
\cline{2-3} 
\cellcolor{yellow} & short text & 7 \\
\cline{2-3} 
\cellcolor{yellow} & short text & 8\\
\cline{2-3} 
\cellcolor{yellow} & short text & 9 \\
\cline{2-3} 
\multirow{-10}{*}{\cellcolor{yellow}\begin{sideways}TEST\end{sideways}}  & short text &  10 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When there is a long text in one of the cells, the text of the left cell ("TEST") is aligned somewhere:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,a4paper,12pt,pdftex]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.025\textwidth}|p{0.775\textwidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}|}
 & \textbf{foo} & \textbf{bar} \\
\hline
\hline 
\endfirsthead
 & \textbf{foo} & \textbf{bar} \\
\hline
\hline
\endhead
\cellcolor{yellow}& short text & 1 \\
\cline{2-3} 
\cellcolor{yellow} & medium text ........ ....... ....... ....  ........ ....... ....... .... ........ ....... ....... ....needs two lines & 2 \\
\cline{2-3} 
\cellcolor{yellow} & short text & 3 \\
\cline{2-3} 
\cellcolor{yellow} & short text & 4 \\
\cline{2-3} 
\cellcolor{yellow} & medium text ........ ....... ....... ....  ........ ....... ....... .... ........ ....... ....... ....needs two lines & 5 \\
\cline{2-3} 
\cellcolor{yellow} & very long text ....... ......... ........ ....... ....... ....... ........ ............. ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... needs lots of lines & 6 \\
\cline{2-3} 
\cellcolor{yellow} & short text & 7 \\
\cline{2-3} 
\cellcolor{yellow} & medium text ........ ....... ....... ....  ........ ....... ....... .... ........ ....... ....... ....needs two lines & 8\\
\cline{2-3} 
\cellcolor{yellow} & short text & 9 \\
\cline{2-3} 
\multirow{-10}{*}{\cellcolor{yellow}\begin{sideways}TEST\end{sideways}}  & short text &  10 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I align the text of the left column in the second example?

Comment: Is your tabular really a longtable which could break across pages? If yes what should happen if the page break is at the places of `TEST`?

Comment: It's a two page table which I break manually after the "TEST" section using the \newpage command

Comment: Here are the images of the two tables (I am not allowed to add them in the question) https://www.dropbox.com/s/z24or3i6795w3vk/test1.png  and https://www.dropbox.com/s/exdfcvfw9q9dr5c/test2.png

Comment: In general I try to avoid `multirow`. I would in your case probably use tikz with `[remember picture]` to place nodes in the corners and then connect them. But it would be some fine tuning to get the size correct. Another way is to nest tabulars, but this could get a bit difficult due to the headers. Beside this I would much less lines ;-).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From my experience `multirow` is not capable of a correct vertical alignment, if it spans multi-line cells. You can, however, adjust the alignment manually using the `fixup`-parameter:

```
% \multirow{nrows}[bigstruts]{width}[fixup]{text}
\multirow{-10}{*}[3em]{\cellcolor{yellow}\begin{sideways}TEST\end{sideways}}
```

Other possibilities for solving this problem are discussed in "[Centering mutirow text in a table whose cells contain several lines of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30551/centering-mutirow-text-in-a-table-whose-cells-contain-several-lines-of-text)" and "[How can I achieve proper vertical spacing for long blocks of text within a \multirow?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26080/how-can-i-achieve-proper-vertical-spacing-for-long-blocks-of-text-within-a-mult)".

Comment: thx - it's not the solution I hoped but it seems the best way to use the `fixup`-parameter

Answer (score 3):

I also solved it with a quick fix: combining a parbox with a vspace within multirow

```
\multirow{5}{*}{\parbox{1\linewidth}{\vspace{1cm} something something}}
```

Answer (score 2):

This table is easy and straight forward to produce using [cals](https://ctan.org/search/?phrase=cals). Nothing special, only standard commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cals, xcolor, rotating}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}


\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}

\begin{calstable}

% Defining 3 column relativ to each other and relativ to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/1000*100\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/1000*775\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/1000*125\relax}
            }
% The tabular fills the text area

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.4pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}        % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}

\def\yellow{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty % Define colour on-off switch
\def\cals@bgcolor{yellow!30}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

\def\tb{\ifx\cals@borderT\relax     % Top border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderT{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderT\relax\fi}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Botton border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderR{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\lb{\ifx\cals@borderL\relax     % Left border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderL{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderL\relax\fi}

% H1
\thead{%
\bfseries
\brow
    \yellow\nc{tlr}\yellow
    \alignL\cell{Foo}
    \alignC\cell{Bar}
\erow
\mdseries
}
% R1
\brow
    \yellow\nc{lr}\yellow
    \alignL\cell{short text}
    \alignC\cell{1}
\erow
% R2 Body
\brow
    \yellow\nc{lr}\yellow
    \alignL\cell{short text}
    \alignC\cell{2}
\erow
% R3 Body
\brow
    \yellow\nc{lr}\yellow
    \alignL\cell{short text}
    \alignC\cell{3}
\erow
% R4 Body
\brow
    \yellow \nc{lr}\yellow
    \alignL\cell{short text}
    \alignC\cell{4}
\erow
% R5 Body
\brow
    \yellow\nc{lr}\yellow
    \alignL\cell{short text}
    \alignC\cell{5}
\erow
% R6 Body
\brow
    \yellow\nc{lr}\yellow
    \alignL\cell{short text}
    \alignC\cell{6}
\erow
% R7 Body
\brow
    \yellow\nc{lr}\yellow
    \alignL\cell{short text}
    \alignC\cell{7}
\erow
% R8 Body
\brow
    \yellow\nc{lr}\yellow
    \alignL\cell{short text}
    \alignC\cell{8}
\erow
% R9 Body
\brow
    \yellow\nc{lr}\yellow
    \alignL\cell{short text}
    \alignC\cell{9}
\erow
% R10 Body
\brow
    \yellow\nc{blr}\alignC\sc{\vfil\begin{sideways}TEST\end{sideways}}\yellow
    \alignL\cell{short text}
    \alignC\cell{10}
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par % \par needed to align the tabular

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. In that environment, you merge cells both vertically and horizontally with the command `\Block` and the content of the block is positionned at the mathematical center of the `\Block`. That means that vertically, you count the number of logical row and not the number of physical lines as with `multirow`.

```
\documentclass[ngerman,a4paper,12pt,pdftex]{report}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|p{0.025\textwidth}|p{0.775\textwidth-6\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}|}
 & \textbf{foo} & \textbf{bar} \\
\hline
\hline 
 & \textbf{foo} & \textbf{bar} \\
\hline
\hline
\Block[fill=yellow]{10-1}{\rotate TEST}& short text & 1 \\ \Hline
 & medium text ........ ....... ....... ....  ........ ....... ....... .... 
   ........ ....... ....... ....needs two lines & 2 \\ \Hline
 & short text & 3 \\ \Hline
 & short text & 4 \\ \Hline
 & medium text ........ ....... ....... ....  ........ ....... ....... .... 
   ........ ....... ....... ....needs two lines & 5 \\ \Hline
 & very long text ....... ......... ........ ....... ....... ....... ........
    ............. ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... 
    ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ 
    ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... 
    needs lots of lines & 6 \\ \Hline
 & short text & 7 \\
 & medium text ........ ....... ....... ....  ........ ....... ....... .... 
   ........ ....... ....... ....needs two lines & 8 \\ \Hline
 & short text & 9 \\ \Hline
 & short text &  10 \\ \Hline
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

A better solution with the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass[ngerman,a4paper,12pt,pdftex]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Table},
]{
  colspec={|c|X[5,m,l]|X[1,m,c]|},
  rowhead = 1,
  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
  cell{2}{1} = {r=10}{yellow7}, % multirow
}
\hline[1pt]
 & Foo & Bar \\
\hline[0.8pt]
 \begin{sideways}TEST\end{sideways} & short text & 1 \\
\cline{2-3} 
 & medium text ........ ....... ....... ....  ........ ....... ....... .... ........ ....... ....... ....needs two lines & 2 \\
\cline{2-3} 
 & short text & 3 \\
\cline{2-3} 
 & short text & 4 \\
\cline{2-3} 
 & medium text ........ ....... ....... ....  ........ ....... ....... .... ........ ....... ....... ....needs two lines & 5 \\
\cline{2-3} 
 & very long text ....... ......... ........ ....... ....... ....... ........ ............. ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... ....... ....... ........ ...... needs lots of lines & 6 \\
\cline{2-3} 
 & short text & 7 \\
\cline{2-3} 
 & medium text ........ ....... ....... ....  ........ ....... ....... .... ........ ....... ....... ....needs two lines & 8\\
\cline{2-3} 
 & short text & 9 \\
\cline{2-3} 
 & short text &  10 \\
\hline[1pt]
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have observed that `b` parameter as vertical positioning ([here](https://github.com/pietvo/multirow)) works better in centering the text as compared to `c` parameter.

Hence try using

```
\multirow[b]{nrows}{*}{Your Text}
```